# Using AngularJS' Typeahead for selecting multiple values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ with the Static arrays example in the Typeahead section...

If I wanted to do something like being able to select multiple states, one after the other, how would I add that into the Typeahead code? Also, is there anyway that when I click the input - it shows all the selections possible with a scroll bar?

Edit: I really like this one however it doesn't allow for multi-select: http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using: https://github.com/tamtakoe/oi.multiselect

Answer (score 0):

try to use chosen:

[chosen at github](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Chosen works very well with angular and css frameworks, because chosen only hide your original multiselect component, without affect DOM parts.